# A field initializer cannot reference a non-static field method or property

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I do not understand why the constructor (constr) and  _test1 are erroring here?
Could somebody give me an understanding?

```
namespace ScratchPad
{
    class loading
    {

        public string _text1 = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\Defect DB\noemi.xlsx";


        string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _text1 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"; 

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        var selectStatement = String.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", "excel");// _test2 is not working.
        OleDbDataAdapter adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectStatement, con);

        con.Open(); // if i leave _test1 like that then, this will fail.  private string _text1;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adaptor.Fill(table);

     } 
}
```

Comment: you probably want to put some of this code in a method on your class, and string `constr` is not a constructor - constructor is a method that has the same name as that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code inside the constructor for the class, but keep in mind that the code will only fire off if you create an instance of Loading by the line of code Loading myloading = new Loading(). Also, please capitalize the L in Loading. It's proper class naming convention.

```
namespace ScratchPad
{
    class Loading
    {
     public string _text1;
     public string constr;
     public OleDbConnection con;
     public string selectStatement;
     public DataTable table;
        public Loading()
        {
        string _text1 = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\Defect DB\noemi.xlsx";


        constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _text1 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"; 

        con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        selectStatement = String.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", "excel");// _test2 is not working.
        OleDbDataAdapter adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectStatement, con);

        con.Open(); // if i leave _test1 like that then, this will fail.  private string _text1;

         table = new DataTable();
        adaptor.Fill(table);
        }

     } 
}
```

Comment: Of course you are correct in this, but you leave the OP with another problem to handle. What is the fate of that DataTable variable in that constructor? All this work for nothing

Comment: I changed the code to instantiate them with the class. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. The only thing that i got as an error now is the "var" insertion: the contextual keyword "va" may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code. Any idea

Comment: By the way, the reason why i am pulling the table from excel is because i want to select some columns from there aka, A, B, C and serialize the rows associated to that column. i know how to serialize that and how to import the excel...not clear how i will store the values on the particular columns (i have more than 3) that i know the name and use those

Comment: Re-write public var selectStatement to public string selectStatement

Comment: Does this answer your original question?

Comment: 1. I have a table from excel that i import to a data table (see above).

Comment: and  I also have the code to serialize examples of excel. However, i am not quite sure how to store the column values that i need (A, B, C, D) and do the serialization afterwards. The example of the table is below

Comment: other item other Description defect name X Y Other Other
  fab1 short a 300 400  
  fab1 short a 400 400  
  fab2 short b 400 400  
  fab2 short a 600 400  
  fab3 open a 600 400

Comment: Please create another question, and vote on the answer to let everyone know this particular one is answered.